# Trimming leading zeros with regex

Tags: regex, leading-zero

I'm struggling to get a regex expression to work.

I need to allow the following transforms based on the existence of leading zeros...

> 1. 001234 -> 1234
> 2. 1234 -> 1234
> 3. 00AbcD -> AbcD
> 4. 001234.1234 -> 1234.1234
> 5. 001234.000002 -> 1234.2
> 6. 001234/000002 -> 1234.2

I've found the expression matches works well for transforms 1, 2 & 3 but I'm not sure how to match the (optional) second section demonstrated in 4, 5 & 6.

```
^0*([0-9A-Za-z]*$)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the zeros with following regex :

```
/(?:^|[./])0+/g
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK6bV2/1)

and replace the second group with first group (`\1`).

For example in python i can do following :

```
>>> s="""001234
... 1234
... 00AbcD
... 001234.1234
... 001234.000002
... 001234/000002"""

>>> [re.sub(r'(:?^|[./])0+',r'\1',i) for i in s.split()]
['1234', '1234', 'AbcD', '1234.1234', '1234.2', '1234/2']
```

Comment: Thanks - this works but returns the zeros - how do I get it to return the values with the zeros stripped?

Comment: @Drammy As is said you need to use  a replacer function like `re.sub` in python that i added to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0+)(.+)
```

Group 2 should be result.

Comment: i get this  1234/000002 for 001234/000002.. as in the example 6.